# OrderBy on List<string> property

Tags: linq, sql-order-by

How do I do an OrderBy for List type properties in the following manner?

I'd like to order by first name and first string in the list

UnOrdered : ResearcherNames

Zoe Las, Joe Smith

Kyle Burt

Adam Zing

Ordered: ResearcherNames

Adam Zing

Kyle Burt

Zoe Las , Joe Smith

Here's how my class looks like

```
public class assignments
{
    public List<string> ReseacherNames { get; set; }
    public List<string> ClientUserNames { get; set; }
    ------Other Properties ------
}

 //fill list
 combinedAssignments = new List<assignments>();
 foreach(var item in db) 
 {
    combinedAssingments.Add(item)
 }

 //need to sort by ResearcherNames
 combinedAssignments = combinedAssignments.OrderBy(x => x.ReseacherNames ).ToList();
```

When I run with above OrderBy call I'm getting "At least one object must implement IComparable." error.

**Attempt**

So I realize I have to use a IComparer for List types and have implemented a comparer as following:

```
 public class RecordComparer : IComparer<List<string>>
 {
        public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            if (x == null)
            {
                if (y == null)
                {
                    // If x is null and y is null, they're 
                    // equal.  
                    return 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    // If x is null and y is not null, y 
                    // is greater.  
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // If x is not null... 
                // 
                if (y == null)
                // ...and y is null, x is greater.
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    // ...and y is not null, compare the  
                    // lengths of the two strings. 
                    // 
                    int retval = x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length);

                    if (retval != 0)
                    {
                        // If the strings are not of equal length, 
                        // the longer string is greater. 
                        // 
                        return retval;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // If the strings are of equal length, 
                        // sort them with ordinary string comparison. 
                        // 
                        return x.CompareTo(y);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public int Compare(List<string> x, List<string> y)
        {
            var result = 0;
            if ((x != null && x.Count>0 )&& ( y != null && y.Count>0) )
            {

                return Compare(x[0], y[0]);
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var rc = new RecordComparer();
 combinedAssignments = combinedAssignments.OrderBy(x=>     x.ResearcherNames,rc).ToList();
```

No error message, however results are not alpha sorted.

Comment: I'm confused - are you trying to order the `ResearcherNames` within the object?  What's the relationship between `ResearcherNames` and `ClientUserNames`?

Comment: There's no relationship between ResearcherNames and ClientUserName fields, just happen to show there are other fields like List<string> in this class. I'd like to sort my list by these list<string> types

Comment: Your data and expected output shows that you want to order `ReseracherNames` (`List<string>`), but your codes shows that you are trying to order `combinedAssignments` (`List<assignments>`). So which one do you actually want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No IComparer needed.  This would give you the assignments in order of the first researcher's first name:

```
combinedAssignments = combinedAssignments
  .OrderBy(x => x.ReseacherNames.FirstOrDefault())
  .ToList();
```